# How to decrypt fields by mysql that was encrypted by laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

In my laravel app I need to retrieve data by query builder, and i have some fields that are encrypted

How i can decrypt it by query builder inside **selectRaw** method instead of model cast attribute or getters because when we use query builder these methods will not be executed

I tried Aes_decrypt mysql function but it's return null

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a mutator https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

On your model :

```
protected function theField(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn (string $value) => decrypt($value),
    );
}
```

decrypt : https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-decrypt or use the `Crypt` facade

But if you use Query Builder, you will have to decrypt over the collection :

```
$data = DB::table('users')->where(...)->get()->transform(fn($row) => [
    'decrypted' => decrypt($row->encrypted)
]);
```